# Recent posts loop return wrong permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, permalinks

I have a loop for showing recents posts in wordpress:

```
        <ul class="homepage-section homepage-era-jazzu fusion-clearfix">
        <?php
            $args = array( 'numberposts' => '4', 'post_type' => 'era-jazzu', 'post_status' => array('publish', 'future') );
            $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
            foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
                echo '<li><a href="' . get_post_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], '260-160') . $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
            }
            wp_reset_query();
        ?>
        </ul>
```

It works but not in the way I would love to. My issue is following - sometimes one of the recent posts is 'scheduled' post. That's why it's permalink is UGLY like: `http://yourdomainurl.com/?post_type=jazz&p=10603`

how to make it work with nice permalink like yourdomainurl.com/nice-address

? from admin standpoint everything is ok (so in dashboard i see nice permalinks; only issue is with my loop code).

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `get_post_permalink($recent["ID"])` on `get_permalink($recent["ID"])` and everything will work fine.